# nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'

Tags: cassandra

I tried to build a 6 nodes cassandra cluster with 2 DCs on AWS. I created EC2 with t2.micro on public subnet with public IP. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04. After install, I changed the listen_address to private IP 10.0.0.119 and seeds set the same IP. I set the endpoint_snitch to Ec2Snitch and cassandra instance was running and when I issued nodwtool status I got below error:

> root@ip-10-0-0-119:/etc/cassandra# nodetool status
> nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.

I tried other snitch such as GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and SimpleSnitch. no help.

I checked google for multiple posts and none of them helps. please advise if there is suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you didn't modify the JMX port, the most likely causes of the `Connection refused` exception are:

1. Cassandra is not running.
2. JMX port `7199` is bound to a different IP.

Point (2) is only a possibility if you've modified the configuration in `conf/cassandra.yaml` in which case you need to connect with `nodetool` using the values (IP, port) you set yourself.

Otherwise, it is almost always because Cassandra is not running so you need to review the Cassandra `system.log` for clues. In my experience, it is usually a misconfigured `cassandra.yaml`. Cheers!